# Is there data leakage in my code (ROC curve giving 1.00 AUC score)?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, pca, roc

People told me there was data leakage when splitting my data into the testing and training set. My goal is to plot the receiver operating characteristic curve using log regression of both the original data (after standardization) and the principal component analysis model.

However, the receiver operating characteristic curve just gives me a 1.00 area under the receiver operating characteristic curve score for every plot.

Edit: As David pointed out, I was able to achieve a ROC AUC score of < 1 for the PCA model. That's half the problem solved! The log reg model on the regular dataset still gives me a perfect score of 1.00.

Here is the code to assign my features and labels.:

```
# Import wine dataset.
df_1 = pd.read_csv ('./wine.data', delimiter =',', header = None, nrows=200)

# Feature Selection (dropping strongly correlated features):
df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.columns[7], axis='columns')
df_1

# Separating out the features, columns 1 to 13.
x = df_1.iloc[:, 1:13].values 

# Separating out the target, column 0, with classes 1, 2, and 3.
y = df_1.iloc[:, 0].values 

# Standardizing the features (centering and scaling).
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

# Dataset is split into training set (70%) and testing set (30%).
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.30,random_state=123)

#PCA is performed for 2 components
pca_2 = PCA(n_components=2)
X_train_pca_2 = pca_2.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_pca_2 = pca_2.fit_transform(X_test)
```

And here is the rest of my code, in case data leakage actually isn't the problem:

```
# Create logistic regression function for one vs all classifier.
logreg = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, multi_class='ovr')

# Train the model using the original pre-processed dataset.
model = logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the class of each wine in the testing data.
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred

array([3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1,
       2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2], dtype=int64)

# Train a second model using the PCA.
model_PCA = logreg.fit(X_train_pca_2, y_train)

# Predict the class of each wine in the testing data.
y_pred_PCA = model_PCA.predict(X_test_pca_2)
y_pred_PCA

array([3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3,
       3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1,
       2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2], dtype=int64)

# Binarize the labels
y_train_binary = label_binarize(y_train, classes=[1, 2, 3])
y_test_binary = label_binarize(y_test, classes=[1, 2, 3])
n_classes = y_train_binary.shape[1]

# Score for One vs Rest Classifier
y_score = model.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

# Score for PCA model
y_score_PCA = model_PCA.fit(X_train_pca_2, y_train).decision_function(X_test_pca_2)

fpr1 = dict()
tpr1 = dict()
roc_auc1 = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr1[i], tpr1[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test_binary[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc1[i] = auc(fpr1[i], tpr1[i])

fpr2 = dict()
tpr2 = dict()
roc_auc2 = dict()
for j in range(n_classes):
    fpr2[j], tpr2[j], _ = roc_curve(y_test_binary[:, j], y_score_PCA[:, j])
    roc_auc2[j] = auc(fpr2[j], tpr2[j])

# Plotting ROC Curve of all 3 classes using logistic regression on the orginal data set and the PCA model
plt.figure()
lw = 1
plt.plot(fpr1[0], tpr1[0], color='purple',
         lw=lw, label='LogReg Class 1 (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc1[0])
plt.plot(fpr1[1], tpr1[1], color='blue',
         lw=lw, label='LogReg Class 2 (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc1[1])
plt.plot(fpr1[2], tpr1[2], color='aqua',
         lw=lw, label='LogReg Class 3 (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc1[2])
plt.plot(fpr2[0], tpr2[0], color='orange',
         lw=lw, label='PCA Class 1 (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc2[0])
plt.plot(fpr2[1], tpr2[1], color='green',
         lw=lw, label='PCA Class 2 (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc2[1])
plt.plot(fpr2[2], tpr2[2], color='red',
         lw=lw, label='PCA Class 3 (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc2[2])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC Curve')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you clarify this question? model_PCA and model both have ROC of 1.0?

Comment: So I did log reg on 2 data sets. The first is the original (standardized) data set, and the second is a log reg on the pca model. Then Im supposed to generate a ROC curve on both log regressions but it’s giving me an AUC score of a perfect 1.00 for both, which I’m sure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might actually be getting perfect results. I haven't dealt with the dataset, so I don't know how possible that is with a logistic regression function. However, you have 1 major flaw in your code, where you overwrite your pca model with a model trained on the whole feature space. see:

```
y_score_PCA = model_PCA.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

You are using the whole X_train vector, rather than, what I would expect to be correct,

```
y_score_PCA = model_PCA.fit(X_train_pca_2, y_train).decision_function(X_test_pca_2)
```

or alternatively, don't refit the model

```
y_score_PCA = model_PCA.decision_function(X_test_pca_2)
```

That essentially makes your scores the same for both models.
I would then expect your AUC for the PCA model to be < 1.0. If thats not the case, there are likely more problems, since you seem to have different predictions for each model.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This one fix would make such a big difference for my grade lol. I'm trying to apply the same logic to double check my logreg score, but I think that one has a different mistake. Now class 1 has a score of 0.98, class 2 has 0.93, and class 3 has 1.00 (which i think is fine). 
But i think the logreg scores shouldn't have scores of 1.00, since class 3 using the pca model has a score of 1.00, and both model's predictions for class 3 doesn't match.

Comment: I've also tried using the last line you provided, but that one game me an error saying X was expecting only 2 features instead of 12. Not sure if that might help.

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I believe that, if there exists some threshold where you perfectly predict y, you will have an auc of 1.00. that means you can have different predictions using model.predict (which is probably using 0.5 as the threshold) and still have a perfect auc for both, because each model is a perfect predictor using different thresholds.